# Git: Deciding between branches and multiple repositories

Tags: git, version-control, gitolite

I'm working on moving an organization to use git, and I'm trying to determine which would be a  better approach, either having a single repo with multiple branches (development, integration and release), or having multiple repos for each track.

The simpler approach would be to have branches and just a single repo, and this is my preferred solution. I plan to use gitolite for access control to branches.

Comment: What's the advantage to having multiple repos?

Comment: I would definitely go with branches. You would lose history using different repositories. development should be trunk, "release" could probably just be tags of whatever got released with a version number.

Comment: What is the projected size of your repository?  If you're talking about some hundreds of GB's that can be a different story.  Also, what is your user distribution?  How many products will be built from this repo?  Squeezing some thousand users in one repo can sometimes be a bad idea if they can be cleanly cut into 10 groups and use their own repos.

Comment: @Carl, If you look at Dictator and Lieutenants Workflow on the page http://progit.org/book/ch5-1.html you'll see why I'm considering multiple repos.

Comment: @PeontheGreat, The repo's currently about 20G, if that makes a difference. There are perhaps 50 developers.

Answer (score 1):

We have had both. Using separate repos is the better solution. We have about 50 and there are no issues, work is more easily organized. Gitolite is great for administering them all.

Answer (score 1):

As you replied you have 20GB repo and 50 users so far.  Not too bad for single repo.

What you need to ask yourself is that how fast will this repo grow in size and users.

Size of repo directly affects your ability of doing off-line backup (if you care).  Number of users determines how heavy the load will be for the repo server w.r.t. network and disk I/O.  Most modern servers on the market shall handle your need well so far.  It's not the case when your repo is several hundred GBs and thousands of users.

Answer (score 0):

In Hg community it has been about creating new repos instead of branches and named branches were added later. But, creating repositories is still common. With both Hg and Git both branches and repositories are pretty lightweight and depending on your circumstances, it is advantageous to choose one over another.